# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE csv column data with line break

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I would like to import CSV data into MySQL database, below is the example row data of my CSV file:

```
"9C5435D89FCA5E19E0532107A8C074BD","12341234","20180411 163616","ABC","12341234;Testing data.
TestingData.","1"
```

As you can see column 5 have line break (Unix EOL, which is LF), when I import it I got `ERROR 1261 (01000): Row 2 doesn't contain data for all columns`
 
Below is my `LOAD DATA INFILE`

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/opt/mysql/files/table.csv'  
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@uuid,col2,@date,col4,col5,col6) 
SET col1= UUID_TO_BIN(@uuid),col4 = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%Y%c%d %H%i%s');
```

I have tried to set `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`, but getting another error `ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'col6' at row 1`

I have already specified the `ENCLOSED BY '"'`, isn't this should prevent the issue I am facing now? Although there is a line break, but it is still enclosed with `""`, MySQL should tread it as a column data instead of new row of data isn't it?

Is there any way to resolve this? I am unable to change CSV data as the data is meant to have line break in it. `table.csv` is exported from Oracle DB using `spool` command.

Comment: Normalize your "a-la CSV" before importing. Remove excess/wrong linebreaks. Alternatively - load it into temptable, all the line into one field, join errorneously divided adjacent records, then parse and import into the final table.

Comment: I agree. You may need to write some other code to reformat the CSV before it can be imported with LOAD DATA INFILE. For example, if you can replace the line breaks with "\n", it works.

Comment: @Akina what does "a-la CSV" means? Appreciate if you could elaborate more on "Normalize". Thanks!

Comment: @BillKarwin But correct linebreaks will be replaced too...

Comment: 'a-la' means something close to "similar, but not the same". This is from the French language (à la).

Comment: @Akina, One must write code to tell the difference. I didn't say it would be easy! :-)